# Value not getting right answer

Tags: c#

```
int c;
int f = 20;
c = 5 / 9 * (f - 32);
Console.WriteLine(c);
Console.ReadLine();
```

If I run this code c ends up being 0, which is wrong. Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because your calculation is being done in **integer type**. I believe `c` is double type variable.

```
c = 5d / 9 * (f - 32.0);
```

use `32.0` or `32d` so that **one of the operands is `double`**, also do the same for `5/9`.

Also **you need to define `c` as double.**

Comment: `5 / 9` will still be zero.

Comment: actually, you are taking the `Double` result here and putting it into c, which was declared an `int`. truncation will occur and the problem will return.

Comment: @Oren, yup, thanks for pointing that out, I missed that in the question and assumed that `C` is defined as double

Answer (score 3):

the problem is in the following line;

```
5 / 9
```

because c and f are integers.
For instance, if I asked you to divide 11 to 10; you will tell me the result is 1.1. Assume that you do not know about floating point arithmetic, then you will say either it is not possible to divide 11 to 10; or you will say it is 1. Runtime environment does the same, it says it is 0 since you are declaring an integer.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky you are right up to some point; declaring f as an integer results in this situation. but it is not possible to define c as an int and f as a double. Thus, if both are declared as integers, even if the f is removed the result will be still 0.

Answer (score 1):

Habib already explained what is happening. Here is what you could do if you don't want to change `c` to a float or double:

```
c = (int)Math.Round(5.0 / 9.0 * (f - 32.0));
```